# How would i write practice?

Tags: word-choice

How would i write practice in Japanese?
I need to write practice in Japanese as in practicing drawing.
Would it just be 練習 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 練習 is the right word in your context.

Note that 練習 only refers to *practice* as a method of training. It means doing the same thing many times to acquire some skill. You need other Japanese words (such as 慣習 or 実践) to say something like "Japanese business *practice*" or "put the theory into *practice*".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, you *might* be able to use [訓練]{くん・れん} or [鍛練]{たん・れん}.  But these usually translate as "training" or "discipline", and I believe they imply something way more hardcore, like long-term, grueling training and practice.